# retrieve the Quote Detail with c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sdk, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I'm trying to create a custom workflow (for Dynamics CRM 2011) which must send an email with information on the Details Quote from a quote.
I create it in Visual Studio 2010 with the sdk.

The workflow is triggered manualy from a quote.
I am able to retrieve the value of the customerid, but I am unable to get the attached documents or the quotedetails of the Quote, when I launched the workflow I have this exception :

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity.get_Item(String attributeName)
   at CPageCRM.Workflow.QuoteSendMailNotificationRIP.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
```

My code is :

```
//to get the current Quote
 Entity preImageEntity = context.PreEntityImages.Values.FirstOrDefault();
 //preImageEntity is a Quote because I trigger the workflow from a Quote
 //the next two lines work, I can retrieve the good value of the Quote
 string natureDevis = Utils.GetOptionSetValueLabel(service, preImageEntity, "new_nature", (OptionSetValue)preImageEntity["new_nature"]);
 string prospectDevis = ((EntityReference)preImageEntity["customerid"]).Name;
 //I get the exception after that :
 List<QuoteDetail> listQuoteDetail = new List<QuoteDetail>();
 listQuoteDetail = preImageEntity["quote_details"] as List<QuoteDetail>; //I get the exception
```

I don't understand why the quote_details doesn't exist in the dictionnary, because when I do :

```
    Quote devis = new Quote();

   devis.quote_details //<= (the autocompletion is working)
```

I have the same problem when I try to get sharepointdocumentlocation

Anyone have an explication? How can I retrieve the Quote Details and the document attached to my Quote from the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successed with a linq query
I had to search the quote_detail which were linked to the quote :

```
var queryQuoteDetail = from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("quotedetail")
                       where ((EntityReference)r["quoteid"]).Id.Equals(context.PrimaryEntityId)
                       select r;
```

Answer (score 1):

A comment and potential answer.

My comment is when retrieving stuff out of the Images I often find it easier to let the compiler grab the proper type and just use 'var'.

My answer is that quote_details isn't just a field, but an actual 1-n relationshp (by looking in the metadata browser). You may need to get the related entities in a separate retrieve.

**Edit:**
For example: _service.Retrieve("quote", quoteId, new ColumnSet("quote_details"))
will retrieve the quote details from the service. However, you could also check and see if you are passing in the quote_details attribute from the PreImage.

Comment: Thanks for yout comment, 
I tried to get the quote_details with _service.RetrieveMultiple but O got the same problem.
Do I have to use a LINQ query ? or there is another method?

Comment: I tried what you said :
var entite = _service.Retrieve("quote", context.PrimaryEntityId, new ColumnSet("quote_details"));
but I got an exception with the message :
'Quote' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'quote_details'.
I also tried :
var queryAccount2 = from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("quote")
                                            where ((EntityReference)r["quoteid"]).Id.Equals(context.PrimaryEntityId)
                                            select r;
And when I try r.Attributes.ToList(); there is nothing about quote details.
Any suggestion ?